# Html to content management system

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi I started learning web design couple of months ago and I just made my first functional site using HTML, CSS and JavaScript and PHP for my form. I wanted to find out if there is anyway I can transfer my whole site to a CMS without redesigning it. Thanks

Comment: There are simply not enough  details here to answer what is a very broad question.  otherwise is is simply "it depends" - on a great number of specifics

Comment: Hi Moses Ngwerume, welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently as it stands your question is far too broad to give you a reasonable answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for assistance on asking programming-related questions in an effective manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use some frameworks like CodeIgniter or WordPress. These are the most loved and widely used frameworks in PHP.

Comment: Thank you so much @Himadri Mandal. Let me explore it